# How to block accessing the beanstalk web app via ip address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have deployed my web app in aws beanstalk environment and added a hosted zone and then added SSL cert. So now the website can be accessed through a secure domain name. But I found the same can also be accessed via entering an ip address. I don't want my web site being accessed through ip address. How can I block this? Also I noticed this ip address is not the ip address of EC2 instance in which my app lies.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you using Nginx or load balancer?

Comment: @Adiii I am using load balancer

Comment: Did you tired the answer?

Comment: @Adiii :) 
Actually I have another concern that even though my web site is secure (ssl is applied) when accessing the web site via IP address,it goes to insecure way. Actually I have added the redirect rule in httpd.conf file so that all http request  redirects to https. And it works when I use the domain name but don't work when I use IP address. Please see below rule I used in http conf file.



<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

Comment: why you are not adding a redirect in ALB?

Comment: @Adiii 
I have added two listener HTTP and HTTPS in load balancer. Both rediretcs to HTTP port of EC2 instance.

Comment: I got it working. It was actually the browser cache made the issue. When I cleared the cache and tested with Ip address and it redirects to https path.

Answer (score 1):

> Also I noticed this IP address is not the IP address of EC2 instance
>   in which my applies. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Seems like that IP address belongs Load balancer. One way is to Set host-based routing in the load balancer, only particularly `host` will be served for example `api.example.com` and send fix response if the host does not match.

[image]

request otherwise section can be with fix response, so only request with `api.example.com` can be served.

[image]

Comment: Very useful answer. Note that Host is now "Host header..." in the interface.