# How to prevent accesing AWS beanstalk application through IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

I have a docker application hosted on AWS beanstalk, and I have configured such application with R53 to access it via a domain name, let's say example.com. Also that application has an IP address for example 50.50.50.50.

What I need is that when a user types in the browser http://50.50.50.50, it gets redirected to http://example.com, how I can achieve that in AWS?

Thanks

Comment: Your application must do this, e.g. using nginx config. R53 has nothing to do with that.

Comment: isn't it possible to achieve only through some AWS configuration?

Comment: Maybe if you have ALB, you could do some redirections based on the IP. But I'm not sure about that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to block accessing the beanstalk web app via ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796325/how-to-block-accessing-the-beanstalk-web-app-via-ip-address)

Answer (score 1):

The response here [How to block accessing the beanstalk web app via ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58796325/how-to-block-accessing-the-beanstalk-web-app-via-ip-address?rq=1) helped me to redirect an ip address to a domain name, using ELB rules.

Answer (score -1):

It's not quite clear what you mean by "preventing access through IP".

If the IP is public, you can't do much. That's just how TCP/IP works.

However, if your intention is to keep the original name generated by Beanstalk hidden from public, then you can deploy Beanstalk application in a VPC with its load balancer being "internal". That prevents the load balancer from having a public IP. You can then have a public load balancer with a public IP to which the domain name gets resolved. You still have a public IP for the external load balancer, but there is no way to get to the load balancer created and managed by Beanstalk.

If you have an internal DNS zone in AWS that you'd like to use, then you won't need the externally reachable (from internet) load balancer. This way your application is not reachable from internet.